# C# "?" used in get; set declaration

Tags: types, modifier

What is the significance of the "?" in this declaration: public string? Make { get; set; }

searching through Microsoft documentation, I cannot find answer to my question

Comment: see: [Nullable value types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the string can have a null values.

Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types